# How do customise input range slider?

Tags: html, range

I noticed the range slider on Iconic looks great.
[image: Slider on Iconic]

Even better on IOS. How do they do it?

I clumsily copied and pasted what I saw via Chrome dev tools inspector to http://m.dabase.com/r/ but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the answer. Its working fine for me. Hope it should helpful for you.

**Html:**

```
<div class="form-range-control"><input type="range" max="100" min="10" value="100" step="1"></div>
```

**css:**

```
.form-range-control {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #afe0fc;
  padding: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
 .form-range-control input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;width:100%; 
 }
 .form-range-control input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #078dd8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab; 
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/4s62X/)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. http://m.dabase.com/r2/ But can you please  boil it down to what actually changes the slider to that round orb?

Comment: @hendry, You need to add the css class .form-range-control input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb for round orb. So add these css class to your  m.dabase.com/r2. Hope it should work. Please try and let me know. Thanks

Comment: Odd, how .form-range-control input[type="range"] { -webkit-appearance: none; } seems so important.

Comment: @hendry, Please refer these link http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/. Hope it should help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/TUx6xNA1dv3OJowBEDQj?p=preview

CSS:

```
.tour-sidebar {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 77px;
line-height: 18.571409225463867px;
margin-top: 54.599998474121094px;
width: 222.5px;

}





.form-range-control {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #afe0fc;
  padding: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 5px; }
  .form-range-control input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: white;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 1px; }
    .form-range-control input[type="range"]:focus {
      outline: none; }
  .form-range-control input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #078dd8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab; }
    .form-range-control input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active, .form-range-control input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:focus {
      background: #056da7;
      cursor: -moz-grabbing;
      cursor: -webkit-grabbing; }
```